# NestedRecyclerview slow performance android kotlin

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I have a vertical recyclerview with 4 different types of views, each view has a horizontal recyclerview. My problem is that the main thread gets stuck for 5 seconds or so when loading everything, and looking at the layoutmanager I discovered that it is loading all the items from the vertical recyclerview and all those from a horizontal recyclerview. I read that this can happen when the view being inflated is very complex, but can I manage it somehow so that it doesn't load all at once or at least doesn't block the main thread?

[image]

this is my home fragment

class HomeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
private val viewModel by viewModels<CustomerViewModel> {
    CustomerViewModelFactory(ApiCallsRepositoryImpl(DataSource(RetrofitClient.webservice)))
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.bind(view)

    //local json to test home
    LoadDataHome()

}




private fun LoadDataHome() {
    val jsonString = readJsonFile(binding.root.context)
    val gson = Gson()
    val homeResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonString, HomeResponse::class.java)

    val itemlist1 = mutableListOf<HomeResponseItem>()
    itemlist1.addAll(homeResponse)
    val adapterPrincipal = HomeResponseAdapter(itemlist1)
    binding.rvPrincipal.layoutManager =
        LinearLayoutManager(binding.root.context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    binding.rvPrincipal.adapter = adapterPrincipal
    adapterPrincipal.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

private fun readJsonFile(context: Context): String {
    val inputStream = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.json_home)
    val size = inputStream.available()
    val buffer = ByteArray(size)
    inputStream.read(buffer)
    inputStream.close()
    return String(buffer, Charset.defaultCharset())

}
```

}

HomeResponseAdapter.kt

```
class HomeResponseAdapter(private var itemList: List<HomeResponseItem>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return GetHomeResponseViewHolder().get(viewType, parent)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = itemList[position]
    BindHomeResponse().Bind(holder, item)
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {

    return when (itemList[position].idContenido) {
        "SquareBanners" -> 4
        "PillButtons" -> 1
        "MiniBanners" -> 3
        "Productos" -> 2
        else -> 5
    }

}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return itemList.size
}
```

}

what am i missing?